# Enterprise Library C# WCF & Mutliple UI (Silverlight,UI,ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, enterprise-library

I am wondering if anyone out there on here has been able to succesfuly use the Enterprise Library to work across n-Tier Layer Structure, where the UI is of different Mediums.

I have to Design a WCF Common Library Service Layer that will be working across 
the following Platforms:

- Silverlight
- WPF
- ASP.NET MVC

Just some reference documentation or point me in the right Direction. Thought someone out there may have done the same kind of thing, but wouldn't mind a bit of help of where this may have been talked about or done before.

Thanks

Robbie

Comment: Since Silverlight and WPF are so similar. What do you need to do in your WPF application that you cannot do in silverlight?

Comment: Our business is all around Data Files from Multiple Providers with Alot of Data going between Tiers across alot of Applications, and Silverlights Sandbox is not great with File IO, and dont really want to have to Upload a 1gig Data File (We get 10 of these every day) over the wire through WCF through silverlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two projects may be interesting for you to look at:

- [Domain Oriented N-Layered .NET 4.0
  App Sample](http://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com/) (From MS Spain)
- [Layered Architecture Sample for
  .NET](http://layersample.codeplex.com/)

Comment: That first one is Great. Thanks heaps @Forgotten Semicolon

Answer (score 0):

The p&p team created a Silverlight integration pack for the Enterprise Library. You should be able to reuse some of the application blocks that exist on the destkop, although they have a few differences to better support Silverlight.

Download and help on MSDN: [Enterprise Library](http://www.msdn.com/entlib) (Although I suggest you download and install the specific blocks you'd like using NuGet).

See [this blog](http://blog.jdom.com.ar/2011/05/enterprise-library-and-silverlight-hand-in-hand/) For a summary of high level differences with the desktop version.